# Is "$('.sp .tabs span:nth-child(5)').trigger('click');" equivalent to "$('.sp .tabs span:nth-child('+ startPanel + ')').trigger('click');"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is `"$('.sp .tabs span:nth-child(5)').trigger('click');"` equivalent to 
`"$('.sp .tabs span:nth-child('+ startPanel + ')').trigger('click');"` in terms of functionality and purpose if the startPanel variable has the value 5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The resulting strings are identical:

```js
var startPanel = 5;
var str1 = '.sp .tabs span:nth-child(5)',
    str2 = '.sp .tabs span:nth-child('+ startPanel + ')';
console.log(str1 === str2); // true
```

So it won't matter which one you use when calling `$`.